# my account is under vote down attack

Tags: support, down-votes, user-accounts

who is moderator of this website, because my account is under attack
im pretty sure its just one person sending me these [too much vote down](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/12377/muster-mark?tab=reputation)

Answer (score 13):

As no single account can cast more than one down vote on any particular post it is clear that more than one person feels that some of your posts are not *"useful and clear"*.

If any one person is engaging in a pattern of arbitrary downvoting it will likely be reverse by an automatic process that exists for that exact purpose.